# How to pass state object from child to parent in React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am making an Api call to get address details, like address_line1, address_line2, area, city, country, pincode.

In the child component I am only showing address_line1, address_line2, country, pincode.

Below are the snippets from my **child component**

```
const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);

if (result.status === 200 && result.data.status === 'success') {
      setOptions(result.data.data);
    }
```

Then I am mapping the result in my app:

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
  {options.map((i, index) => cityTile(i))}
</ScrollView>;
```

my cityTile component:

```
const cityTile = (item) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        // what to do here
          navigation.goBack();
      }}>
      <CityTile >
        <Text>
          {item.address_line1}, {item.address_line2}, {item.country},{" "}{item.postCode}
        </Text>
      </CityTile>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

When a user clicks on a result displayed on the screen, then it should go back to previous screen, which is my parent component. I have given navigation at `onPress` on `cityTile` component.

Below are the snippets from my **parent component**:

```
const AddressSection = ({navigation, dispatchAction, profileState}) => {
  const [stateVar, updateStateVar] = useState({
    address_line_1: '', address_line_2: '', area: '', city: '', pincode: '', country: '',
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!profileState.loading && !profileState.error) {
      updateStateVar({
        ...stateVar,
        address_line_1: profileState.address.address_line_1,
        address_line_2: profileState.address.address_line_2,
        area: profileState.address.area,
        city: profileState.address.city,
        country: profileState.address.country,
        pincode: profileState.address.pincode,
      });
    }
  }, [profileState.loading]);
};
```

As you can see I am using `useEffect` to update the state when page opens for the first time in parent component.

But I don't know how to update the states in parent component when changes happens in child component.

I know that I have to pass state from child to parent, but I am not able to figure out how to do this.

Please help, this is the last functionality of my app, and I am all stressed out on how to do this.

Comment: You need to use something like `useContext()` or Redux to pass data from child component to the parent component

Comment: Use redux for this purpose

Comment: @FazalUrRehmanFazal I have to do this without redux

Comment: then create profileState in parent component in Parent Component  then  create function in Parent component and pass this function as a props to child component in which update parent component state from child state
In parent COmponent:
const [profileState,setProfileState]=useState

 getDatafromChild(val){
setProfileState(val)
})

render(){
 return(<Child sendData={this.getDatafromChild}/>);
}

In childComponent:

props.sendDate(result.data.profileDate)

Answer (score 1):

Pass a function from parent to child and then pass the state from child as argument to that function which in order will change the state in parent as you code

In Parent Component:

```
getDatafromChild(val){
    console.log(val);
}
render(){
 return(<Child sendData={this.getDatafromChild}/>);
}
```

In Child Component:

```
callBackMethod(){
   this.props.sendData(value);
 }
```

Comment: but this will not result in running useEffect bcz useEffect is running conditionally when profileState.loading changes